# Polybase configuration for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, polybase

According to Microsoft's documentation after installing PolyBase I should run the following code.

```
exec sp_configure @configname = 'polybase enabled', @configvalue = 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

When I try to execute this command it displays an error. How can I add 'polybase enabled' to the configuration using sp_configure ?

> Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 62 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The configuration option 'polybase enabled' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option

What I've done so far :

1. PolyBase is installed.
2. I checked `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('IsPolybaseInstalled') AS IsPolybaseInstalled;` - it returns 1.
3. I enabled `EXEC sp_configure 'hadoop connectivity', 7;`
4. My TCP is enabled.
5. My PolyBase is running.
6. On the PolyBase tab, I see two "Scale-out Groups" : Head and Compute.

sys.configurations

1. polybase network encryption = 1
2. allow polybase export = 1
3. show advanced options = 1

Comment: Did you verify that advanced options are "shown"? Do `USE master;`,`GO`, then `EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option', '1'; RECONFIGURE;`. [How to check advanced options in SQL Server?](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/how-to-check-advanced-options-in-sql-server)

Comment: @TT. Yes, I checked it and it is set to "show advanced options = 1"

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is wrong, in 2016 all you need to enable is "hadoop connectivity" which you've already done. Now check the status of the Polybase services, and you should be good to go.